# I'd like Alexa to announce a monthly reminder

Tags: amazon-echo

I'd like Alexa to announce a monthly reminder on the same day each month, but it seems she only knows "weekly", "daily", etc.  Is there another way?

Comment: Do you specifically need it on the same day each month? [This page](https://www.trifexis.com/blog/authors/admin/2017/how-to-create-monthly-dosing-reminders-using-alexa) has an example of asking for a reminder 'in one month' but I haven't been able to test if it works or whether it fits your needs.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's a non-existent future, at least as of the start of this year: check out [this thread](https://www.amazonforum.com/forums/devices/echo-alexa/469834-recurring-reminders-monthly-and-every-other-week) on the amazon forum.  Charlie444 writes,

> Weekly and daily reminders are great but please add the ability to set monthly and every other week reminders!!

...and Kristen C from the Amazon Staff wrote back,

> Great suggestion Charlie444! If you haven't already, I also recommend sending feedback through the Alexa app by selecting the ? icon next to your name in the menu.

So it looks like for the moment, it's not an implemented feature.  I'd recommend doing as Kristen suggested as well: send feedback through the Alexa app.  The more people feedbacking about this, the more likely it is that they'll do something about it.